# Emulator settings to be able to use download manager

Tags: android

What settings in emulator do I have to change to be able to use DownloadManager class to download as the app is crashing whenever I am trying my  code to run on emulator?
This is the code that I am using
Starter method is a button click event method that starts the download.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DownloadManager dm;
    EditText e;
    Uri uri;
    Long reference,ref;
    IntentFilter i1;
    DownloadManager.Request req;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        i1=new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED);
        dm=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        BroadcastReceiver rec= new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ref=arg1.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Continue download?");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want this download to continue?");


                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                    // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dm.remove(ref);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download aborted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                    dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(rec, i1);

    }

    public void starter()
    {
        //String url=e.getText().toString();
        //if(url !="" & url!="")
        {
            uri=Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4");
            Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            .mkdirs();
            //req=;

            reference=dm.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"test.mp4"));

        }

    }
```

Comment: It can happen if app is crashing. Did you try running app on device?

Comment: Did u add internet permisson to your manifest file?

Comment: yes app is running on device

Comment: besides, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Post Logcat output:when your app crashed, it will show "Caused By" in the logcat output. Check the line no. reported in logcat to map it with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling exception. Use try catch block for downloading the file. Check whether the internet connection is available or not. If the internet connection is available, then only proceed with downloading and show the user the alert dialog which asks for continuity. Otherwise cancel the download.

Also, if you are using a internet connection with proxy settings, you need to set these proxy settings for emulator also.